# Create a dataframe using left_anti spark/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following DF

```
ID NAME VAL
-----------
1  John 5
2  Anna 6
3  Josh 12
4  Paul 10
```

And I have this DF

```
ID
--
2
3
```

I'm doing a left_anti join using pyspark with the below code

```
test= df.join(
    df_ids,
    on=['ID'],
    how='left_anti'
)
```

My expected output is:

```
ID NAME VAL
1 John 5
4 Paul 10
```

Although, when I run the code above i got an empty dataframe as output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that with the following.

```
df = (df.join(df_ids, on=df["ID"]==df_ids["ID"], how='left')
  .where(df_ids["ID"].isNull())
  .select(df["*"]))
```